# Purchase digital service while traveling in the EU

Tags: european-union

I am wondering what type of VAT is due when purchasing digital goods while traveling in the EU.

I found this related to the topic: [Your Europa](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/shopping/vat/index_en.htm)

However, my use case is not covered.

So my question is: If I (EU, but non-German citizen, German tax resident) travel to France from Germany and purchase a digital good from Spain using my German card, do I pay French or German VAT?

My understanding would be that I pay based on where I am "established" at the time of shopping, which is France in this case, but I am not 100% confident in my interpretation.